# DualSim: Select Data SIM for each app

Tags: mobile-data, dual-sim, spotify

I'm wondering if with a DualSim smartphone with Android can be a made a customization like: "for this app use data of SIM1, for this app use data of SIM2".

On one of the 2 SIMs I have, there is a plan for flat Spotify traffic, so I can listen to music w/o consuming data volume.
I want to make Spotify use always data of a specific SIM, even if the other one is configured as default.

Is this possible? An app-level data configuration?

Comment: See if this [app works for you](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.joaormf.mtkcontrol.free) , if it does, it offers Tasker plugin